# Overload << operator for msg

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Simple and maybe stupid question, but is it possible to overload the << operator for ROS messages? When a message is generated this operator is automatically overloaded for them, but I would like to change the way they are printed for plotting purposes.

Wilson

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211304/overload-%3C%3C-operator-for-msg/) by [HououinKyouma](https://answers.ros.org/users/22280/hououinkyouma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The C++ compiler only allows one operator overload for each method signature.

If you want to print your messages in a plot-friendly format, you can write a function that converts messages to custom formatted strings, and print those.

You should also investigate the `-p` option to rostopic echo, to see if it can do what you need: `rostopic echo -p /my_topic`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HououinKyouma](https://answers.ros.org/users/22280/hououinkyouma/) on 2015-06-15**:
I see. I didn't know it was not possible to overload an operator again. The -p option seems useful, but I'm writing my results to a file so I can't use that now. I guess I'll just convert the messages using a function, thanks.